# Twitter search api with geocode hardly returns any hits

Tags: python, api, twitter

My request only returns twenty or so hits. Notice I set the radius to be 5000km which is ridiculous, that's because I used 50 first but got too few hits, so I increased it. But even at 5000km, I'm still getting the same few results. I'm using `Python 3.5`.

Here is the code:

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = 'xxxxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxxxxxxxx'
access_token = 'xxxxxxx'
access_token_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
results = api.search(q="Global Warming",geocode="40.7142700,-74.0059,5000km",count=100)
for result in results:
    print (result.text.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Do you get more results when not specifying  `geocode`?

Answer (score 1):

Twitter limits how far back in the past you can search to about one week. You have reached that limit. You can see this for yourself if you inspect the `created_at` field of the last tweet returned.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing on tweets which:

- Lack location
- Located outside of 1,000 distinct “sub-regions” from given location

When searching on tweets with the `geocode` field,  the `API` will first search for tweets with geolocation specified, otherwise it will use the location from the user profile.

From the `Search API` on [`Geolocalization`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search):

> **Geolocalization**: The search operator “near” isn’t available in API,
>   but there is a more precise way to restrict your query by a given
>   location using the geocode parameter specified with the template
>   “latitude,longitude,radius”, for example, “37.781157,-122.398720,1mi”.
>   When conducting geo searches, the search API will first attempt to
>   find tweets which have lat/long within the queried geocode, and in
>   case of not having success, it will attempt to find tweets created by
>   users whose profile location can be reverse geocoded into a lat/long
>   within the queried geocode, meaning that is possible to receive tweets
>   which do not include lat/long information.

From the [`search/tweets`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets) doc:

> A maximum of 1,000 distinct “sub-regions” will be considered when using the radius modifier.